# Doctrine get repository of all models that extends given abstract class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two models: `NoteItem` and `TaskItem`. Both extends from `AbstractStreamItem`:

```
abstract class AbstractCommentsItem
{
    …
}

class CommentItem extends AbstractCommentsItem
{
    …
}

class TaskItem extends AbstractCommentsItem
{
    …
}
```

Now I want to get repository of both models in one `getRepository` command.

Is it possible somehow? I thought about single table inheritance, but not sure if it's the right approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Single Table Inheritance is a valid solution here. You will be able to do:

```
$entityManager->getRepository(AbstractCommentsItem::class);
```

to get a single repository for all subtypes.

I'm actually doing that in my current project.

Comment: Ok, I am a bit confused right now. So AbstractCommentsItem should be the @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")? Is there a solution using @MappedSuperclass, because presented classes structure reminds me more of this approach.

Comment: Ok, @MappedSuperclass won't work here. Found in documentation: "A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able".